# CoronaSDK APK OBB GooblePlay alignment

Tags: alignment, apk, coronasdk

I have an application with a size of 81 MB. I had to divide it into APK file and OBB. APK has a size of 6.2 MB, while OBB 75.1 MB. I do not know how to publish the application in now GooglePlay. Already signed APK file. But I can not use the command zipalign on the APK (can not find the files that are in the OBB). I do not know how in this situation so divided publish the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just add OBB file as expansion file on screen AFTER apk upload.
Only files in APK are lua scripts, all assets are in expansion file.